# Is it possible for an LED to blink at 10GHz? Context VLC aka LiFi Experiment

Tags: led, frequency, oscillation

According to this article: http://eandt.theiet.org/news/2014/jul/li-fi-sisoft.cfm originally found while reading the Wikipedia page on LiFi, Sisoft has been able to produce 10Gbps (10Gigabits per second) throughput using a single LED.

In my experience, a simple Light Emitting Diode cannot "blink" more than say at 5MHz. So 10GHz sounds nearly impossible and therefore I'm questioning the feasibility of their experiment simply based on the physical limitations of a diode. Can an LED be bread-boarded to blink at 10GHz? It raises the question of whether or not this "experiment" could have possibly transmitted 10Gbps, perhaps with modulation and more than one diode...

Comment: I doubt that anything is going to work at 10 GHz on a breadboard.

Comment: There are LEDs that can do it, but I think they are laser diodes.   Those that are used for fiber communication.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li-Fi

Comment: the article does not refer to a single LED

Comment: Agreed that nothing will work at 10GHz on a breadboard. If you look at the archive.org link they appear to be using common diodes. And it's true that the article does not clarify what type of diode was used. "In 2014 a new record was established by Sisoft (a Mexican company) that was able to transfer data at speeds of up to 10 GB/s across a light spectrum emitted by LED lamps" from Wiki.

Comment: 10 years ago when I worked on [MOST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOST_Bus), getting an LED to blink at 50 Mbps required a very specially designed LED. Later they got to 150 Mbps (I don't know exactly what modulation scheme). I would be very surprised if there's now an LED able to modulate at 1 GHz, much less 10 GHz.

Comment: There are lots of things about the linked article that don't look right.  The test equipment shown in the photo would not be suitable for the task and there would not be a solderless breadboard in sight.  I don't think phosphor based LEDs would be an option, but even with multi-wavelength (several LEDs of different colors) and amplitude modulation, 10Gbps doesn't sound plausible and is going to require significantly more complex equipment than is pictured.

Comment: Agreed Dean, it all looks wrong. I think I'll ask a professor at my local university and see if it deserves to remain on Wikipedia.